# nginx reinstalled automatically?

Tags: apache2, nginx, tor

i had once nginx installed and after same time i removed it

I use apache as my webserver

now when i tried to go to my own onion address in my tor browser, i get the welcome to nginx site??

how is this possible??

I tried to re remove nginx but when i run

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

nothing happens or it tells me nginx is not installed therefore it wasnt removed

now i tried to run

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

i get this message:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
```

What happened and what can i do to fix it??

Comment: You probably need to stop the nginx(`sudo service nginx stop` ) before try to remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx
```

If that says that it not installed, try

```
 ps -ef |grep www-data
```

And see if you see any of the workers present. If so, you could try to stop

```
 sudo service nginx stop
```

If I had to guess, when you uninstalled the service didn't shut down the way it should have.

You may need to install again

```
 sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Then stop it 
     sudo service nginx stop

Then purge it

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx
```

Comment: i did exactly what you said but if i type in localhost i get the nginx site and if i go to my .onion site i get the nginx site aswell

Comment: When you purged did it say it was installed? Also did you see the nginx worker processes when you ps -ef |grep www-data?

Comment: yes before removing nginx i had 4 workers after removing it i had 0 workers

Comment: now after nginx is supposed to be removed i see 3 workers

Comment: So there was 0, but then it started up again or something cause now you see 3. Hmm. This is very odd

Comment: Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: Okay, so you purged, but workers are still there. You try to remove and it says it not installed. Try `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`. Question, does apache2 now start?

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.

Comment: if i run sudo apache2ctl start i get that:

Comment: Do a full reboot and then check to see if workers show up. Is there still /etc/nginx directory?

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.

Comment: yes etc/nginx is still there

Comment: Does it auto start again if you reboot

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge nginx-common`

Comment: yes it starts again     if i run above code i get following   E: Command line option --purge is not understood

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge remove nginx-common`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package remove

Comment: Sorry man, I'm on my phone and distracted. `sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx-common`. I gotta run though, sorry if none of this helped. Like I said before, we're it me, I would install again and then stop service and uninstall again. I use nginx as well (on my pi) and I just purged removed and setup again with no issues.

Comment: i removed nginx and apache and reinstalled apache it works now again, what you prefer to host onion sites, nginx or apache?? also do you know how i can host multiple onion sites??

Comment: No experience with .onion sites. I personally like Apache, but Raspberry Pi B only has 512mb ram, so I had to learn nginx. I assume it would be done as a vhost, but you may need to do some googleing

Answer (score 1):

First stop nginx service, before attempting to remove it. I have tried this and it's working:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove
```